# Derivation of Universal Variables

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

Does anyone know of link to the derivation of the [Universal Variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_variable_formulation)?

This is in regards to [Kepler's equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation). The Wikipedia link didn't have enough information for me, and the [Colorado page](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=kepler+universal+variable+Colorado) doesn't explain how they came up with $S$ and $\chi$.

A universal variable is the universal anomaly in the universal Kepler equation.  It is traditionally marked as chi.  There is a derivation in Battin books `An Introduction to the Mathematics and Methods of Astrodynamics`.

Comment: I"m assuming you want to google the Hamiltonian-Jacobi equation.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer is that what it is called?  I only know it as universal variables.

Comment: It seems like you're talking about action-angle variables, which are well-suited to periodic motion.

Comment: I take it the reference given by wikipedia (Danby, J. M. A. (1988), Fundamentals of Celestial Mechanics, Willman-Bell) doesn't help?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I don't own that resources that is why I am looking for something online.

Comment: I take it [no library near you](http://www.worldcat.org/title/fundamentals-of-celestial-mechanics/oclc/18192420?referer=di&ht=edition) has it, either?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I am over 100 miles away from my University and I doubt public libraries will carry it.

Comment: I've never heard of "universal variables" either, but they do indeed sound like specific instances of action-angle variables. Given that Wikipedia has a properly-referenced article that says they exist but doesn't give a hint as to what they are, I feel this is a good question. Who knows - there may be general techniques for action-angle-ing central force problems that someone can write a great answer about.

Comment: @ChrisWhite a universal variable is the universal anomaly in the universal Kepler equation.  It is traditionally marked as chi.  There is a derivation in Battin books `An Introduction to the Mathematics and Methods of Astrodynamics` but I don't own this resource.

Comment: Fundamentals of Astrodynamics (Bate, Mueller, and White) has a decent explanation in Chapter 4.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using **Orbital Mechanics for Engineering Students** by Howard Curtis available on [Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Orbital_Mechanics_for_Engineering_Studen.html?id=2U9Z8k0TlTYC&source=kp_cover&redir_esc=y) has a great derivation of the Universal Variable formulation, see chapter 3.7, as well as step by step algorithms and example Matlab code for calculation.

I have been using it as a basis for a python program I am developing (as a hobby) and highly reccomend it.

For the *S* term in the Universal variable equation you are looking for the Stumpff functions, Wiki link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stumpff_function). The text above also covers them with Matlab code.

Comment: Perhaps writing out the results rather than just providing links would be more helpful to people...

Comment: @honeste_vivere very true, however Dustin has asked for the Links in his question, also I'm not sure about copywrite for publishing code from the textbook I mentioned..!